# Expressing the roots of $y^5 + 11y^4 - 77y^3 + 132y^2 - 77y + 11 = 0$ in terms of of $\zeta_{11}$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots, radicals, roots-of-unity

Is there a concise way to express the roots of,
$$x^3 + 7x^2 + 7x - 7 = 0$$

using the root of unity $\zeta_7$?

Similarly, is there an analogous expression for the solvable quintic,
 $$y^5 + 11y^4 - 77y^3 + 132y^2 - 77y + 11 = 0$$

in terms of of $\zeta_{11}$?

**P.S.** Note the similar-looking,
$$z^5 + 11z^4 + 44z^3 + 77z^2 + 55z + 11 = 0$$
has $z = \big(\zeta_{11}-\zeta_{11}^{-1}\big)^2$.

Comment: Pari/GP's nfisincl function gives $[-2x^4 - 2x^3 - 3, -2x^5 - 2x^2 - 3, 2x^5 + 2x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 - 1]$ for the $\Bbb{Q}[\zeta_7]$ inclusion and $[-6x^9 - x^8 - 4x^7 - 3x^6 - 3x^5 - 4x^4 - x^3 - 6x^2 - 5, -2x^9 - 5x^8 + x^7 - 3x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 - 5x^3 - 2x^2 - 4, 2x^9 + 3x^8 + 5x^7 + 6x^6 + 6x^5 + 5x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 1, 3x^9 - x^8 - 3x^7 + 2x^6 + 2x^5 - 3x^4 - x^3 + 3x^2 - 2, 3x^9 + 4x^8 + x^7 - 2x^6 - 2x^5 + x^4 + 4x^3 + 3x^2 - 1]$ for $\Bbb{Q}[\zeta_{11}]$

Comment: @sharding4: Ouch, I was hoping there was a short and common formula like in the postscript. How about if we use a rational form $P(x)/Q(x)$?

Comment: @sharding4: How would Pari deal with the postscript example? Will it recover the same relation given above?

Comment: It returns $[x^6 + x^5 - 2, x^7 + x^4 - 2, x^8 + x^3 - 2, -x^9 - x^8 - x^7 - x^6 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2 - 3, x^9 + x^2 - 2]$  Your $\big(\zeta_{11}-\zeta_{11}^{-1}\big)^2$ corresponds to the last embedding $x^9+x^2-2$

Comment: That first embedding into $\Bbb{Q}[\zeta_7]$ is equal to $(\zeta_7+\zeta_{7}^{-1})^3+3(\zeta_7-\zeta_{7}^{-1})^2+6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\;t^7=1\;$ and $\;t\ne1,\;$ then $\;x=-1+2/(t+t^{-1})\;$ is a root of $x^3 + 7x^2 + 7x - 7 = 0\;$ but the six primitive $7$th roots come in conjugate pairs giving the three roots of the cubic in $x$.

If $\;t^{11}=1\;$ and $\;t\ne1,\;$ then $\;z=t\!+\!t^{-1}\!-\!2$ is a root of $z^5 + 11z^4 + 44z^3 + 77z^2 + 55z + 11 = 0$ but the ten primitive $11$th roots come in conjugate pairs giving the five roots of the quintic in $z$ and the five roots of $\;y^5 + 11y^4 - 77y^3 + 132y^2 - 77y + 11 = 0\;$ are from $\;y=(2-u)(1-u+u^3)\;$ where $u:=t+t^{-1}.$